# Rabbit MQ Windows very high CPU with no workload

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rabbitmq

Erl.exe is sat at 90%+ CPU whilst the rabbit server is basically idle.
It's a fresh install on Windows 2012R2, Rabbit version 3.6.6
Nothing in the logs, but I have noticed that the figures for GC / context switching are sky high:

GC operations   84,190/s
GC bytes reclaimed 325,660,781/s
Context switch operations 284,047/s

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I see Couchbase users have the same problem when on Windows. It smells like an issue with Erlang on Windows.

Comment: No sadly not, in fact we stopped using it and went back to using a Linux host

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone has found a reason for this on machines that are sometimes put in hibernation or sleep mode: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/myl74gsYyYg